# Deployment Issue: React application not rendering properly on github pages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I have created a `react` `redux` front end app. The app is working perfectly fine using node CLI and accessible using localhost:3050 or localhost:8080. However, if I try to run production build using github pages the page only renders partially. The same is observed if I open the production `index.html` file directly in the browser. I have searched for hours but not able to find the any clue. Here is the [github repo](https://github.com/muhammed-salman/items-random-rater/) and the [public url](https://muhammed-salman.github.io/items-random-rater/) of the project. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Here is some of the configuration and package files

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "items-random-rater",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "author": "Muhammed Salman Shamsi",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "test": "mocha --require babel-polyfill --require babel-core/register --require ./test/withDom.js --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "clean": "rimraf public",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production npm run clean && webpack -p",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server",
    "deploy": "npm run build && gh-pages -d public"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.10.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "eslint": "^5.13.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "gh-pages": "^2.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jsdom": "^15.1.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.1",
    "mocha": "^6.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.7.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.json**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

const VENDOR_LIBS = [
  "lodash","react","react-dom","react-redux",
  "redux","axios"
];

module.exports = {
  mode: env || 'development',
  entry: {
    bundle: ['babel-polyfill','./src/index.js'],
    vendor: VENDOR_LIBS
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        test: /\.css$/
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['env','react','stage-2']
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: '/public/',
    compress: true,
    port: 8080
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'style.[contenthash].css'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    })
  ]
};
```